# django post_save: update_or_create not working

Tags: python, django, django-signals

```
class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)




class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,



class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
        Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                    null=True,blank=True)      

    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
            def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
                teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,
                                                                Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels,
                                                                Courses=instance.Courses)
            for each in teachers:
                if created or teachers.exists():
                    print("if")
                    StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
                        pk=each.id,
                        Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                        Subject_Section_Teacher=each

                    )
```

Inserting data is working perfectly but when I update the **existing data** it creates another record not update

note: I already tried this **StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create** and **StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create**, but it still the same result

Comment: You don’t seem to be using the update_or_create function anywhere in the code above?

Comment: I already tried that, but its add another record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition

```
for each in teachers:
    if created or teachers.exists():
```

is wrong, `teachers.exists()` will be **always true**, since you already iterate through `teachers`.

Another problem is, that [signal functions shouldn't be an instance/class method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) - **move it outside of your model**. Currently the `sender` parameter would actually be `self` and so on, so `created` would be wrong as well. (or give it a `@staticmethod` decorator)

Since you want to create the record only during `StudentsEnrollmentRecord` creation, you should handle the `created` parameter at the beginning of the signal function - this also saves you some queries.

Also, give your signal function a more meaningful name, maybe `generate_subjects`?

So the signal could look like this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return
    teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(...)
    for each in teachers:
        StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(...)


class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `if` statement and the way you create new instances. try changing the code as the follow:

```
 for each in teachers:
     StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create_or_update(
            Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
            Subject_Section_Teacher=each
     )
```

Comment: And why are you assigning the `pk` and `Subject_Section_Teacher` at the same time with the same value?? Can you post your models structure?

Comment: I edit my question sir, please help me with my problem.

Comment: The problem is in your if statement's logic. ` if created or teachers.exists():` You are checking if the the record is created for the first time or if there is an old `StudentsEnrolledSubject` exists.I will change my answer accordingly

Comment: There's a bit more problems that just the `if` in OPs question